# How to set flow variable inside twilio function

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

I have twilio flow, which calls autopilot and autopilot calls functions, I need to set the flow variable or widget variable inside the function so that when autopilot exits, i can use that variable in flow. 
Its all on twilio, not using any own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values you want access to from within your Twilio Studio Flow, after the Autopilot Widget "Session Ended" path, using the Autopilot Remember Action.

[Add Autopilot variables into Studio Flows](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/studio#add-autopilot-variables-into-studio-flows)

[Autopilot Remember Action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/remember)